# Object instantiation in Python

Tags: python

I have the following python code for the class PortDataState given below.

```
class PortDataState(dict):
    # dict: Port class -> PortData class
    # slimed down version of OrderedDict as python 2.6 doesn't support it.
    _PREV = 0
    _NEXT = 1
    _KEY = 2

    def __init__(self):
        super(PortDataState, self).__init__()
        self._root = root = []          # sentinel node
        root[:] = [root, root, None]    # [_PREV, _NEXT, _KEY]
                                        # doubly linked list
        self._map = {}

    def _remove_key(self, key):
        link_prev, link_next, key = self._map.pop(key)
        link_prev[self._NEXT] = link_next
        link_next[self._PREV] = link_prev

    def _append_key(self, key):
        root = self._root
        last = root[self._PREV]
        last[self._NEXT] = root[self._PREV] = self._map[key] = [last, root,
                                                                key]

    def _prepend_key(self, key):
        root = self._root
        first = root[self._NEXT]
        first[self._PREV] = root[self._NEXT] = self._map[key] = [root, first,
                                                                 key]

    def _move_last_key(self, key):
        self._remove_key(key)
        self._append_key(key)

    def _move_front_key(self, key):
        self._remove_key(key)
        self._prepend_key(key)

    def add_port(self, port, lldp_data):
        if port not in self:
            self._prepend_key(port)
            self[port] = PortData(port.is_down(), lldp_data)
        else:
            self[port].is_down = port.is_down()

    def lldp_sent(self, port):
        port_data = self[port]
        port_data.lldp_sent()
        self._move_last_key(port)
        return port_data

    def lldp_received(self, port):
        self[port].lldp_received()

    def move_front(self, port):
        port_data = self.get(port, None)
        if port_data is not None:
            port_data.clear_timestamp()
            self._move_front_key(port)

    def set_down(self, port):
        is_down = port.is_down()
        port_data = self[port]
        port_data.set_down(is_down)
        port_data.clear_timestamp()
        if not is_down:
            self._move_front_key(port)
        return is_down

    def get_port(self, port):
        return self[port]

    def del_port(self, port):
        del self[port]
        self._remove_key(port)

    def __iter__(self):
        root = self._root
        curr = root[self._NEXT]
        while curr is not root:
            yield curr[self._KEY]
            curr = curr[self._NEXT]

    def clear(self):
        for node in self._map.itervalues():
            del node[:]
        root = self._root
        root[:] = [root, root, None]
        self._map.clear()
        dict.clear(self)

    def items(self):
        'od.items() -> list of (key, value) pairs in od'
        return [(key, self[key]) for key in self]

    def iteritems(self):
        'od.iteritems -> an iterator over the (key, value) pairs in od'
        for k in self:
            yield (k, self[k])
```

In another class I am instantiating an object of PortDataState as below

```
self.ports = PortDataState()  # Port class -> PortData class
```

I am very new to Python.I want to know what does self.ports contain? I don't really get what `__init__` function of PortDataState is doing above.Specifically what does

```
def __init__(self):
    super(PortDataState, self).__init__()
    self._root = root = []          # sentinel node
    root[:] = [root, root, None]    # [_PREV, _NEXT, _KEY]
                                    # doubly linked list
    self._map = {}
```

mean?

Comment: so what dou you want to know? the `__init__` calls the init of dict and sets some attributes.

Comment: what is _root and _map and what is root[:]?

Comment: __init__ can be thought of as equivalent to a Constructor. It is called when to Instantiate an object in Python. super(PortDataState, self).__init__()  calls the constructor of the super class i.e. dict

Comment: _root and _map are instance level variables i.e they can be accessed via an instance of this class. root[:] is used to replace all values in the list. You can read more about list slicing here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init__` function in Python is constructor method as any other language. This method initialize class fields (but `__init__` method is not to create object itself, `__init__` only modified object after it has been created). Object creation performed automatically when your write PortDataState() (i.e. when object instantiating).

As for your case object self.ports will contain all methods and variables that **dict** class contained (because PortDataStates inherits from dict). Besides your object will contain:

1. `_PREV`, `_NEXT`, `_KEY` variables (it a static variables and will be shared between each of objects of PortDataState class)
2. `_root`, `_map` - some kind of "protected" members (if your use IDE, e.g. PyCharm, it warn you that this members protected if you try to access to one of these member outside class). But really during execution Python not prevent you to access on member starts with "_" char. (So it's only convention).
3. `link_prev`, `first`, etc. will not be presented in object because its not started with keyword `self`. `self` is object itself.

Comment: To be exact, constructor is `__new__`; `__init__` is initializer.

Comment: @glglgl Equivalent methods in other languages (most notably [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#constructors), [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)) are called constructor without compunction. This is as it should be — after all, such methods do *construct* a full-fledged object given empty space for one. Why invent a new term for what has always been known as constructor?

Comment: @user4815162342 It is not a new term. A constructor as well includes reserving space for the object; besides, `__init__` doesn't get a completely empty space - the type of the object is already set. In contrary, `__new__` really returns the new object, and it even can opt to return an object of a different type (class).

Comment: Yes, `__new__` - create an object (in term of C++ "allocate memory for object") and then pass new clear object to the `__init__` function that added members and methods to this object. Moreover `__new__` can return already created object (it widely used for Singleton pattern)

Comment: @glglgl Again, the use of *constructor* to mean "method that constructs an object, given the space" is well-established in OOP. In that sense the term "initializer" is new and unnecessary. The Python documentation itself [calls `__init__` a constructor](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) (note the last sentence).

Comment: @user4815162342 Is there as well a term for "a facility that creates an object and perhaps allocates memory for it", what `__new__()` would be?

Comment: @glglgl Good question. [Guido himself](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__) just calls it "the `__new__` method", and I couldn't find a consistent name for it elsewhere. ([`effbot.org`](http://effbot.org/pyref/__new__.htm) uses the term "create a new instance" for what `__new__` does, but that's far from a catchy term like constructor.) Python documentation calls the whole class invocation "constructor expression". It is the default constructor expression, implemented in `type.__call__`, that invokes `__new__` and then `__init__` on the returned object.

Comment: @glglgl C++ clearly differentiates between allocation and construction, and the closest equivalent of `__new__` would be `operator new` that takes care of allocating an instance created with `new foo`. But C++ can also construct an object allocated on the stack, or residing in the middle of a pre-allocated container, and altogether avoid invocation of `operator new`. This is not possible in Python, where every object created at run-time must have been ultimately returned by `object.__new__` or equivalent code in the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` initializes the user-defined class so that it can be used as intended.

In this example,

- the `__init__` of the super class is invoked
- the `_root` and `_map` attributes of the object to be initialized (which is `self`) are set so that they can be used later in other methods.

The function is called upon instantiation of a new object (instance) of this class.

What happens with

```
self.ports = PortDataState()  # Port class -> PortData class
```

is that a new object of class `PortDataState` is instantiated, so the `__init__` method is called.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what does self.ports contain?

Python have very usefull `dir()` function.
If you want get the object content write this:

```
print dir(self.ports)
```